# Azure Data Factory: common logic before/after all activities

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

### Objective

I'm going to implement custom auditing on top of ADF pipelines. My ADF pipelines consist of activities of different types: ingesting, Databricks, loading results to data warehouse, etc. At the beggining and the end of each activity I would like to write some information to the auditing database.

### The issue

I don't like to wrap each pipeline activity with extra auditing activies. I would like to do some kind of aspects/advices common for all activities. But I suppose that isn't a way ADF is supposed to be used.

Of course, it's easy to wrap custom Databricks/Python code with auditing, but how about ingesting/uploading activities?

### Question

*What is the best way to implement custom logic before/after all ADF pipeline activities?*

### P.S.

In Apache NiFi it's possible to access NiFi's logs and build a separate parallel pipeline that will parse and write logs to audit database. See [the article](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/NiFi-Easy-custom-logging-of-diverse-sources-in-mere-seconds/ta-p/247947). As far as I know, I can configure ADF to write logs to Azure Storage. Than read logs from there and write to audit database. But this sounds to me like a bad design. Any better options?

Comment: I’m interested in ideas the community has here. But one option is to just use the built-in logging that ADF can load to various places like storage or Azure Monitor. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor

Comment: @GregGalloway I also like to use built-in services over building custom solutions. But decition was made not by me, and the main motivation for custom was cloud-agnostic approach (strange if take into account ADF orchestration). From pros of custom solution (besides cloud-agnostic) I see granularity of details. Still this is another question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to do this apart from the approach you have mentioned i.e. to wrap each activity between pre and post processing logic and get it audited by logging your information to your sink, however I think it would be a good feature if activities natively starts supporting pre and post processing events in ADF itself and allow to invoke webhooks so that any pre and post processing data can be sent over to webhooks.

Further, You can submit an idea or suggestion to the team at
[feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory)